# selenium webdriver python with open("txts.txt")

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I open a list of URLs on new tabs, in Selenium + Python? I want each site to open a new window from the list of URLs in a txt file (like "sites.txt"). Here's how I set things up:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import fileinput
import urllib3
import sys

count = 0
while (1):
        with open("url.txt") as f:
            for line_terminated in f:
                count = count + 0 
            line = line_terminated.rstrip('\n')
        print ()," ", count
        service = Service(r'geckodriver.exe')
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
        try:
                driver.get(line)
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.quit()
        except:
                driver.quit()
                print(), "Error ", line
```

I have tried the script above, and the result is only reading the last URL from list:

```
url.com
```

````py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import fileinput
import urllib3
import sys

count = 0
while (1):
        with open("url.txt") as f:
                for line_terminated in f:
                    count += 1
                    line = line_terminated.rstrip('\n')
                    print (line, count)
                service = Service(r'geckodriver.exe')
                options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
                driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
                try:
                        driver.get(line)
                        time.sleep(5)
                        driver.quit()
                except:
                        driver.quit()
                        print(), "Error ", line
```output

http://www.only_read_lastonfile.com
````

Answer (score 0):

You have a few typos in your script, such as `count = count + 0` (you probably meant `1` to increment the count, and `+= 1` simplifies that).

Your `print()` line is not in your loop, which means it'll only show the last thing you printed. You want:

```py
with open("sites.txt") as f:
    for line_terminated in f:
        count += 1
        line = line_terminated.rstrip('\n')
        print (line, count)
```

And you are taking extra time in spinning up a new driver and calling `driver.quit()` at each loop iteration. You can probably simplify that by reusing an existing driver for each new page load.